# Visual studio 11 MFC component code not removed

Tags: c++, user-interface

Im creating GUI for visual c++ application an Visual Studio 11 Ultimate. When I place a component (button, check box, etc.) on a frame, some code automatically gets added to the source file. **But** when a component is removed/deleted, none of it's associated code gets deleted which creates error when compiling. I then have to manually remove all associated code for a successful compilation.

Is this usual behavior or am I missing something? Also, is there a way to remove all associated code along with the component?

Comment: Short answer: yes, this is entirely normal.

Comment: Then what is it's solution? I don't think I'm supposed to manually remove all the code associated with a component.

Comment: When you tell it to remove something, it removes the declarations that connect the code to the component, but yes, you're supposed to remove the code itself manually.